# Is there a way to reload an excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to parse some logs in a file. The program that add logs runs in the background. I want to look at the file at a given moment and then after a few minutes to reload it and look again.
Is there a menu for that ? a hidden keyboard shortcut ? I don't want to go through the whole close excel and reopen or open multiple windows with the same file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Link your data from within another excel spreadsheet.  Then click the "Refresh Data" button, or create a macro in your new sheet and bind it to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Great. It worked nicely after I realized I need to choose "import external data" from data menu. You get a nice button for "update field" and it reimports my file (along with the special delimeter char).

Comment: Good deal.  Sorry, I should've put that part in there :)

Comment: There's *no* "refresh current file contents" option built in ??

Answer (score 3):

I asked on the beta program for a similar feature years ago but as far as I know, it was never added. (Well, I requested it on Word)

The only thing you can really do is to close the document and reopen.

Sorry!

Comment: typical microsoft